# mysql error : "subquery returns more than one row" but i need more than one row from subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my problem, one is the `USER` table with all details of user and a `REQUEST` table with friend requests from all users to all users. I want to list all the friends of one user who logs into my application.

The `USER` table attributes are,

```
id | uname   | passwd  | fname | e mail  | dob  | mobileno |  habbits | tastes | profession | image  
11 | nagaraj | *****   | naga  | ng@gml  | 3/94 | 998345   | singing  | sports | teacher  
12 | chiraag | ******* | chiru | ch@gml  | 2/93 | 894617   | writing  | music  | student
```

Similarly,  the REQUEST table attributes are,

```
rqstTO | rqstFM  | fname   | e mail | mobile | status   
chirag | nagaraj | nagaraj | ng@gml | 99821  | accepted
```

The tables look like this. Now I want to display the details of the friends( from `USER` table), only those friends who have accepted the request from the user who logged in. Output may be multiple users. The conditions to be satisfied are

1. all details of friends (from user table)
2. `rqstFM` should be the user logged in and `rqstTO` must be the friends to whom he sent requests  (since request table has request details from all to all users)
3. `status=accepted` (they must have accepted the request)

The query I have written is

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE habits='singing' AND uname = ( 
    SELECT rqstTO 
    FROM request 
    WHERE rqstFM ='"+username+"' AND status='Accepted'
);
```

(here `+username+` is the uname of the person logged in obtained from HTML FORM tag). The error I keep getting is **"subquery returns more than one row"** but I do need multiple rows as logged in user may have sent requests to many ppl and among those all who accepted his request, their details need to be displayed from user table. Please, correct my query or provide an appropriate query for my problem

Comment: Please view @madforstrength 's response as this is what you were intending to do.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `IN` instead of `=`:

You can use as mentioned below:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE habits='singing' AND uname IN 
( SELECT rqstTO FROM request WHERE rqstFM ='"+username+"' AND status='Accepted');
```

However using subqueries are not recommended due to performance issues. You should rewrite your query by using `JOIN`

You can use 'JOIN' like below: (I haven`t tested it)

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u
JOIN request r ON u.uname = r.rqstTO 
WHERE u.habits='singing' AND r.rqstFM ='"+username+"' AND r.status='Accepted';
```

Comment: I did use the IN as well but it showed me the same error. Can u kindly give me the query using JOIN for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this (not tested it however):

```
SELECT user.uname, request.fname
FROM user
INNER JOIN request ON request.fname = user.fname
WHERE request.status = 'Accepted';
```

However, I would probably have a bit of a rethink of those tables, maybe this is personal preference but you would likely be better off having a join table that simply contains an id and the username, and then join on two other tables. One containing the requests and one containing the member details.